# Where is TFS Build Explorer in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: tfsbuild, visual-studio-2015

I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RTM on Windows 8. In Visual Studio 2013 the Build Explorer was in Team Explorer -> Builds -> Actions -> Manage Queue. That option no longer exists in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RTM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, that menu option (and a few others) were removed in 2015. The Visual Studio experience has been refocused on the dev showing just the Builds page. We (the tfs build team) expect build admins and those who own definitions to start on the Web and not really use Visual Studio.

That said, if you still have XAML build definitions, then you are tied to Visual Studio to edit those definitions.

Sorry for the unexpected change in behavior.
Jason Prickett

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. We have TFS 2013 and as far as I can tell, there is no way to view the test details of a build via the web portal. So for now, I'll have to continue using the Build Explorer in VS 2013.

Comment: I can't even view the build results or the summary of a build inside visual studio anymore.  when i click on a running/finished build, it goes straight to the browser.  Has the visual studio version been completely disabled then?

Comment: As a "build admin", I feel that this was a very poor design decision. Even without XAML, I edit the MSBuild and PowerShell scripts and check-in changes inside of Visual Studio. And you really can't expect people to "start on the web" when it's still totally broken compared to the Build Explorer.

Comment: As a "build admin" I agree with Al-Muhandis. We edit definitions, kick off builds and enjoyed monitoring the builds in VS. I literally spent over an hour trying to figure out why my build explorer was gone from VS 2015.

Comment: This has been SUPER annoying... need to have both VS2013 and VS2015 up... 2013 because of the Manage Queue of Builds, and 2015 because it now has Code Reviews (only in Premium in 2013 so silly)...   What makes things worse is that both products have the SAME Icon on task bar, so you need to keep clicking the HELP to know which VS your in...    PLEASE add Manage Queue in 2015!!

Comment: This user voice item is older and has more votes: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9549177-bring-back-build-explorer-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 3):

The links that bring up the Build Explorer (Manage Queue) are gone from VS2015. However, if you double-click any build definition in the Team Explorer list of "XAML Build Definitions", the Build Explorer tab will appear.

Comment: Does this work with TFS 2015 and VS 2015? I have this option available when TFS 2013 and VS 2015 are working but for TFS 2015 and VS 2015, this view does not exist.

Comment: Good question.  The configuration we have it TFS 2013 and VS 2015.  We don't have an instance of TFS 2015 to test this with yet.

Comment: We recently updated TFS to 2015.  Double-clicking the XAML build definition still brings up the "View Controller Queue" tab, which looks like the equivalent of what the build explorer was.  Right-clicking the build definition displays a context menu which includes "View Controller Queue".