# TFS and VS2015: How to view builds in studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, team-explorer, tfs-2015

Upgrading from VS2013 I noticed that VS2015 will open the list of builds in the browser (right-click on the definition and "View Builds")

Is there a way to switch back to opening the list in the studio?

Comment: This question isn't about Visual Studio, it's about TFS and Team Explorer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As the behavior changed due to an upgrade of the VS and not the TFS I regard this a VS issue. It still works as desired with VS2013 on the same machine. I will look (or better let someone look) into options on the TFS side.

Comment: Without the proper tags and title you won't get any answers. Don't expect people to google for "View Builds" to understand what you are asking, like I did. Not all (or even most) developers use TFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been removed in visual studio 2015.  Viewing builds can only be done from the Builds web page.

[Where is TFS Build Explorer in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614150/where-is-tfs-build-explorer-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: This isn't very useful but somewhat interesting: the UI itself is not entirely removed. If you do a gated check-in, VS will show a message saying "Your check-in has been queued...Click here to see" - clicking the link will open the build status inside VS.