# TFS - Is it possible to rename a build definition?

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

I can clone one and then delete the original, but the build history is still with the old one.

There has got to be something I am missing.

I don't see a rename option in the menu anyplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the build explorer.  Got it! :D

Comment: Since the issue has been solved, you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Update for new build editor**
If you are using the new TFS build editor renaming a build definition is a lot easier now. From the tasks tab you can now rename it straight away.

[image]

**For the old build editor**

For those using VS2015 the build explorer has had a lot of functionality stripped out of it [as seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614150/where-is-tfs-build-explorer-in-visual-studio-2015). In VSO/Team Services/whatever the new name is to rename a build definition you simply click on the 'Save' button and then when updating the reason for saving you can also rename the definition at the same time.

[image]

[image]